# using jquery to replace text delete my span and his class

Tags: jquery, html

i want to replace the text contained into a span with a class, but with my code, the only thing that happen is that also the span class is deleted

here's the code:

```
    $("input.textInput").on("keyup", function () {
        target = $(this).attr("lang").replace("Text", "Div");
        $("." + target).text($(this).val());
    });
```

and here's the example div:ì (before replace):

```
<div class="targetDiv"><span class="test"> Text to be replaced </span></div>
```

and this is how it looks like after the script (after replace):

```
<div class="targetDiv">Replacing text</div>
```

**EDIT**

Ok, here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xs9t/

Comment: Where is the input element? Post the full code

Comment: What the..? reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: Set the text of the `span`, not the `div`: `$('.' + target).find('span').text( this.value );`

Comment: What is it SUPPOSED to look like after the replace?

Comment: @Barmar I guess: `<div class="targetDiv"><span class="test">Replacing text</span></div>`

Comment: @billyonecan I assume so as well, but it would be nice to get confirmation from the OP. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Example failing fiddle for anyone wanting to have a go: http://jsfiddle.net/8u2Bp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're directly targeting the div, and then calling `.text()` replaces the entire content of the div with the text.

Change this line:

```
$("." + target).text($(this).val());
```

to

```
$("." + target + " span").text($(this).val());
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MtG9B/